# Block until promise is resolved

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, q

Given the following Coffeescript code:

```
for groupID, groupObj of @cache.groups

  #do some other stuff

  #calling this function which is returning a promise
  @callcounter.findNumbers(groupID)
  .then (result) =>
    @cache.groups[groupID].someValue = result.someValue
```

Behind the scenes, the method `findNumbers` is querying an SQL database (using tedious, which doesn't support concurrent queries) and returns a promise (library: Q)

Because of that, code execution shall not go to the next iteration of the `for`-loop until the promise of the previous one is resolved.

How would you do this in a proper way?

Comment: May I ask why the question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is that your calls to `findNumbers` are made sequentially, right? You just have to chain your promises.

Important: because your are using imperative loop and not a [].forEach, you need to scope your `groupID` and `groupObject` variables.

```
globalPromise = null

createScopedPromiseFn = (groupID, groupObject) =>
  return ->
    @callcounter.findNumbers(groupID).then (result) =>
       @cache.groups[groupID].someValue = result.someValue

for groupID, groupObj of @cache.groups
  createPromise = createScopedPromiseFn groupID, groupObj
  # The if here is for initialisation
  globalPromise = if globalPromise then globalPromise.then createPromise() else createPromise()

globalPromise.then ->
  # Here you have finished
```

In this code, the `for` loop iterate without restriction but the promises actually resolve sequentially.

However, I would encourage you to have a functional approach with `reduce` instead:

```
createScopedPromise = (groupIndex, group) =>
  @callcounter.findNumbers(groupIndex).then (result) =>
    @cache.groups[groupIndex].someValue = result.someValue

globalPromise = @cache.groups.reduce (promise, group, index) ->
  if promise
    return promise.then ->
      createScopedPromise index, group
  else # First promise
    return createScopedPromise index, group

globalPromise.then ->
  # Here you have finished
```

Comment: thank you. The functional approach looks promising. There's one drawback though. It seems I shouldn't be doing `#do some other stuff` in the same `reduce` though. Actually, I'm doing this because it would have been easy to do. But it looks wrong to me to do the same thing in your functional approach.

Comment: The iterate with forEach/map another time. It's ok.